# React Native responsive margin and padding

Tags: react-native

I would like to know if setting paddings and margins to a responsive value is the right way to do things in React Native.

For instance, let's say that I have a Button component. My button component has a padding and the text inside should be responsive. I'm already handling text as responsive with my custom function (code below), and works just fine, the problem here is that if a person tries the app in a very small devide, the text inside the button will look cool, but the padding will be way too much compared to the text size, since I'm setting a fixed value. So, is it right to use the same function that calculates the text size to calculate my padding too?

My responsive size calculate function:

```
const scale = width / 375

export const normalize = (size: number): number => {
    const newSize = size * scale

    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        return Math.round(PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(newSize))
    } else {
        return Math.round(PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(newSize)) - 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[react-native-responsive-fontsize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-fontsize) is for resizing font but basically it's for anything with pixels I use for auto margin padding font anything I basically want to dynamically resize that uses pixel (px)

eg

```
    import { RFValue } from "react-native-responsive-fontsize";

    {
       fontSize: RFValue(14),
       padding: RFValue(10)
    }
```

but if you want to manually control it you can use Dimensions

eg

```
import { Dimensions } from "react-native"; 


const width = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width);
```

then you can do your stuff

```
const scale = width / 375

export const normalize = (size: number): number => {
    const newSize = size * scale

    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        return Math.round(PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(newSize))
    } else {
        return Math.round(PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(newSize)) - 2
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right! I've being testing reponsive values since yesterday and using responsive values on margin and padding makes the app much more fluid in small devices.